# Bootstrap 4 form validation: Add same rule for password comparison

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4

I use **Bootstrap 4 / JS form validation** (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles) which works as intended.

I am **trying to add the same formatting and submission rules for a comparison of the two password fields**, password (`'#pw'`) and repeat password (`'#pwRepeat'`), so that it shows the green cell border and checkmark icon when they match and the red cell border and error icon when they don't match.

My **problem is that I can't get it to trigger the invalid format** resp. to set it manually to invalid when the passwords don't match (for corresponding lines see comments below).

Can someone show me how to do this right and also provide a short explanation ?

**My JS:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                var pw = document.getElementById('pw').value; // $('#pw').val();
                var pwRepeat = document.getElementById('pwRepeat').value; // $('#pwRepeat').val();

                if(pwRepeat != pw) {
                    // set cell border color to red and show error icon for invalid input
                    pwRepeat.addClass('invalid'); // not working
                }
                if(form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');    

                // submit if no errors where found
                if((pwRepeat == pw) && (form.checkValidity() === true)) {
                    // do stuff
                }

            }, false);
        });
    },
    false);
})();
```

Many thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Please use `<>` tool for create a complete snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues here.

```
var pwRepeat = document.getElementById('pwRepeat').value;
```

pwRepeat is a value and not an element so the following wouldn't work and addClass isn't correct either.

```
pwRepeat.addClass('invalid');
```

Replace the above with:

```
 document.getElementById('pwRepeat').classList.add("invalid");
```

Given there is no working example the above is untested but should point you in the right direction as to why this currently doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I mixed JS and jQuery here and was too fast in typing this. I will try to create a working example to find out why the colors are still not being set.

Comment: Probably .invalid css border colour isn't overriding the existing border colour. Trying adding !important to it. like .invalid { border : solid 1px red !important;} Failing that, post the CSS and the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I realised that the required default classes are called is-invalid / is-valid and not invalid / valid. Changing this seems to work with the borders and icons.